# What's the best way to notificate user after one year in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I want to send a notification to user which should be sent every year on a specific day. What's the best way to do it in kotlin?

Comment: Use firebase cloud messaging https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad, so is my answer.

First, you need to understand that this work is more related to the backend rather than android.

1. You need to design a login/register method for the backend where you can store user registration date so your backend can inform the user's anniversary
2. Design backend service and send a message using FCM service to inform the user

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can u give me any example?